# Is there any way to configure persistent path/location to collect core dump of a container

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

Is there any official support to configure a downloadable core dump location for a specific deployment/container in GKE?

Imagine we can have something like core-path:

```
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nebula
        - core-path: gs://some-bucket/cores/
```

So that every time the container crashes, I can grab its core file from GCS location.
Sounds very useful feature, if not available in GKE/GCP, what alternative I can do to collect the core dumps?

Thanks for your answers/pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GKE provides support to configure a downloadable core dump location for a specific deployment/container. If the Pod/Container/Node restarts or crashes then we will be losing all the data which was generated in the core-dump folder.

So, GCP introduced an agent called  **Core Dump Collector Agent** in each Node. This Core Dump collector agent will exist as a Daemon Pod / Sidecar container which will collect the data from the location where the core-dumps are created and upload the same data to an external Storage Device which is Google Storage(GCS), Local File Storage etc.

Each Application running inside the Pod will write the core-dump in a location in its file structure. This location will be Mounted Persistent Volume within the Kubernetes Cluster. The Core Dump Agent will watch the Mounted Volume Location, so as soon as some files are getting created in Persistent Volume, the same file gets uploaded in the Google Storage which is outside the cluster and hence we are able to get a centralized path where we can get all core dumps across multiple clusters.We can also mount to an Empty directory as well rather than Persistent Volume. Persistent Volume is taken so that we do not lose any core-dumps in some unforeseen circumstances.

For more information you can refer to the [article](https://faun.pub/handling-core-dumps-in-kubernetes-clusters-in-gcp-b1b2a54c25dc) written by Jayant Chaudhury.